# Create new array from groupings of characters?

Tags: arrays, swift, string, filter, uniq

I have output similar to what is shown below:

> RRRYYYYYGGYGGGGGYRRRRRYYYYGBBBGYYYYYRRRRYYYYGBBBBYYYYYRRRRYYYYGBBBBRRRRRRRRRRRRRYBBBBGGGGGGGGGRRRRGGGGGGGGGGBBBBBBBBBRRRRGGGGGBBBBBBBBBGYGGBBBBBGGYRBBBBBGGGGBBBBGGGGGBBBBGGYYGBBBBGGGGGBBBBRRRRGGGGGBBBYYYRGGGGYYYYYYYYYYYYGGYYYGGGBGGYYYYGGGGGBBBBBBBBGYRYYGGGGGBBBBBBBBGYRYGGGGGGGGGGBBBBBGGGGGGGGGBBBBBBRRRRRRRYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYRRRRYYYYYGGGGGYYYYYYYYYYYYYRYYYRRRGGYYYYYYYYYRRRRGRRRRYYYYYYYYYRRRRRYYYYYYY

I am looking to create a new string or array that lists the characters based on their groupings. For example, the new array would begin like: RYGGRYBYR.... Some letters are errors and should not be accounted for, like the 6th 'Y'. How should I go about this? Please comment if you would like me to clarify my objective. Thanks.

Comment: Why are some letters errors, and not be accounted for?

Comment: And how are we suppose to help you, if we are not sure which are supposed to be accounted for or not?

Comment: @impression7vx if they are not repeating they are errors

Comment: @LeoDabus is correct

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
let input = "RRRYYYYYGGYGGGGGYRRRRRYYYYGBBBGYYYYYRRRRYYYYGBBBBYYYYYRRRRYYYYGBBBBRRRRRRRRRRRRRYBBBBGGGGGGGGGRRRRGGGGGGGGGGBBBBBBBBBRRRRGGGGGBBBBBBBBBGYGGBBBBBGGYRBBBBBGGGGBBBBGGGGGBBBBGGYYGBBBBGGGGGBBBBRRRRGGGGGBBBYYYRGGGGYYYYYYYYYYYYGGYYYGGGBGGYYYYGGGGGBBBBBBBBGYRYYGGGGGBBBBBBBBGYRYGGGGGGGGGGBBBBBGGGGGGGGGBBBBBBRRRRRRRYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYRRRRYYYYYGGGGGYYYYYYYYYYYYYRYYYRRRGGYYYYYYYYYRRRRGRRRRYYYYYYYYYRRRRRYYYYYYY"
var result: [Character] = []
var lastChar: Character?
var repetitions = 0
for char in input.characters {
    if char == lastChar {
        repetitions += 1
    } else {
        repetitions = 0
    }
    if repetitions == 1 {
        result.append(char)
    }
    lastChar = char
}

print(String(result))  // "RYGGRYBYRYBYRYBRBGRGBRGBGBGBGBGBGYBGBRGBYGYGYGGYGBYGBGBGBRYRYGYYRGYRRYRY\n"
```